# Object.values not creating "proper" array

Tags: javascript

I am creating an array using `Object.values()`. When comparing it to a hardcoded equivalent it returns false.

```
var newArr = Object.values({1: 50, 2: 50, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0});
console.log(newArr); // [50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var compareArr = [50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
console.log(compareArr); // [50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
console.log(newArr === compareArr); // false
```

Am I missing something here or should it not return true?

Comment: you compare two arrays with different object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript compares references for non primitive types (for on `==` and `===`). Array is not a primitive type. Meaning if they are not the same instance, the comparison will return false.

Comment: Thank you!
But using == should return true?

Comment: @louis9898 good point. No. I changed my answer. Comparison as a whole work the same way. The difference between == and === is that the later will not do implicit type coercion

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to compare

```js
var newArr = Object.values({
  1: 50,
  2: 50,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  6: 0,
  7: 0
});
var compareArr = [50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
console.log(JSON.stringify(compareArr) == JSON.stringify(newArr)); // true
```